# Angular 7 RXJS Observables timer interval infinite loop start immediately

Tags: angular, timer, rxjs, observable

I'm trying to make these RXJS observables work properly with Angular 7 but I can't figure out what's wrong.

What I want to do is check is there is verify token state every 10 seconds for auth.

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient, HttpHeaders} from '@angular/common/http';
import {interval, Observable, of, timer} from 'rxjs';
import {concatMap, delay, flatMap, takeWhile, tap} from 'rxjs/operators';
import {Token} from './Token';
import {User} from './User';
import {TokenFactory} from './factory/tokenfactory';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TokenService {
  private user;
  private token;
  private tokenLoginUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/login_check';
  private refreshTokenUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/token/refresh';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  private verifyTokenState(): Observable<any> {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('token')) {
      this.getLoginInfo().subscribe(token => {
        this.token = TokenFactory.createToken(token.token, token.refresh_token, Date.now(), true);
        return of(this.token);
      });
      this.token = {};
      return of(this.token);
    }

    this.token = TokenFactory.getTokenFromLocalStorage();
    const timeElapsedInMinutes = (Date.now() - this.token.date_token) / 1000 / 60;
    console.log(timeElapsedInMinutes);

    if (timeElapsedInMinutes >= 59) {
      this.getRefreshToken(this.token).subscribe(jsonToken => {
        this.token = TokenFactory.createToken(jsonToken.token, jsonToken.refresh_token, Date.now(), true);
        return of(this.token);
      });
    }
    return of(this.token);
  }

  private getLoginInfo(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<Token>(this.tokenLoginUrl, this.user, httpOptions);
  }

  private getRefreshToken(token: Token): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<Token>(this.refreshTokenUrl, token, httpOptions);
  }

  public getToken() {
    return timer(0, 10000).pipe(
        flatMap(() => this.verifyTokenState()),
        takeWhile(() => this.token !== undefined && !this.token.isValid)
    );
  }

  public setUser(user: User): void {
    this.user = user;
  }
}
```

The issue I have is that when I call get TokenService.getToken() from inside another component (let's say in a login component after a user clicks the submit button) and I use `timer(0,10000)` the getLoginInfo() and 
getRefreshToken() methods get called in an infinite loop and there are hundred of ajax calls fired.

```
public getToken() {
    return timer(0, 10000).pipe(
        flatMap(() => this.verifyTokenState()),
        takeWhile(() => this.token !== undefined && !this.token.isValid)
    );
  }
```

The thing that I don't understand is that if I use 2000 instead of 0 as first parameter, everything works fine but it's not what I want.

```
 public getToken() {
        return timer(2000, 10000).pipe(
            flatMap(() => this.verifyTokenState()),
            takeWhile(() => this.token !== undefined && !this.token.isValid)
        );
      }
```

What I want exactly is for the observable to have intervals of 10 seconds between calls but I want it to start immediately. I also want to get an observable Token returned from the getToken() after its being returned from the verifyTokenSate() method. So what's wrong exactly? Is there a better way to do it? I want to do this in a reactive way without unsubscribe.

The issues seem to happen in the AuthInterceptor after further invertigation. When I remove in from the module providers, everything is ok. Here is the AuthInterceptor:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';
import {TokenService} from './token.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {map, mergeMap} from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    private token;
    constructor(private auth: TokenService) { }

    intercept(
        req: HttpRequest<any>,
        next: HttpHandler
    ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        let request = req.clone();
        this.auth.getToken().subscribe(t => {
            console.log(t);
            if (t.token) {
                console.log('token valid');
                request = req.clone({
                    setHeaders: { Authorization: `Bearer ${t.token}` }
                });
            }
        });

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```

So what's wrong inside the AuthInterceptor?

Comment: for timer related operation you can use **RxJS interval operator** here is working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ohddud?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100, **here is official documentation:** https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html

Comment: already tried with interval also. The problem is in the AuthInterceptor

Comment: what does this **t** (in your AuthInterceptor) consoles?

Comment: tried passing token as a parameter ...like          `const copiedReq = req.clone({ params : req.params.set('token',this.auth.getToken()) })
        return next.handle(copiedReq);` ?  ,I have used like this in my app for passing token through interceptor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AuthInterceptor maybe intercepting http requests to login/refresh urls, and in turn triggering these calls itself (via this.auth.getToken()), leading to cyclic nature. A possible solution would be to not intercept (or skip) these http requests

```
intercept(
    req: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    // whitelisting certain urls that don't need token check
    if (req.url.includes('/login_check')
        || req.url.includes('/token/refresh')) {
        return next.handle(req);
    }

    // remaining code
}
```

Comment: You are right, this is what caused the cyclic calls, now everything is working perfectly, thank you!